# How to send a serialized leap motion frame containing \0's via zeromq?

Tags: c++, zeromq, leap-motion

I need to send a leap motion frame via network using ZeroMQ.
The send and receive functionality already seems to work but I have a problem with the data being sent.
The Leap::Frame class contains a serialize and a deserialze method which creates a byte string of the given frame (or recreates a frame from a string).
For this simple example I send the string without beeing encapsulated in any class or something else from the client to the server.
The problem is that the byte string seems to have some \0 in it and so only the data till the first \0 arrives at the server.

*The client:*

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Leap::Controller controller;

    zmq::context_t context = zmq::context_t(1);
    zmq::socket_t client = zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_REQ);
    client.connect("tcp://192.168.0.101:6881");

    while(true)
    {
        Leap::Frame frame = controller.frame(0);
        std::string frame_string = frame.serialize();
        zmq::message_t message( frame_string.size() );
        memcpy(message.data(), &frame_string, frame_string.size());
        client.send(message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*The server:*

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    zmq::context_t context = zmq::context_t(1);
    zmq::socket_t server = zmq::socket_t(context, ZMQ_REP);
    server.bind("tcp://*:6881");

    while(true)
    {
        zmq::message_t message;
        server.recv(&message);
        std::string frame_string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size());
        Leap::Frame received_frame;
        received_frame.deserialize(frame_string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These are the first 200 chars of a serialized frame on the client side (total size for a frame with one hand is around 3700 chars). The first of many \0's is at position 149 (highlighted in bold):

s\x1è\x1d\bÒÏ¤\x2\x10ÝËè£§\x1\x1až\x3\b2\"3\n\xf\rEÝ{Á\x15Ì\x1d“C
\x1dæx•Á\x12\xf\r²\b\r¾\x15w/õ=\x1d†³{¿\x1a\xf\rw+ŠB\x15Ò0¡A\x1dB-
\x6B*\xf\rôX\x1a?\x15è\x5G¿\x1d|k7¾2!\n\xf\rœ„ÚÂ\x15¯£ÍC\x1d6´GÂ
\x15\x1fÁ\x18C\x18ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\x1:\x1b\tzù\x1c”hª\x1eÀ\x11jÆaê‘HIÀ
\x19\t‡**\0**p0_@ÀBW\n\x1b\t8O\x13U\x15Õï?\x11Y\x2\a;Y=²¿\x19fó™Æ<Ä²?
\x12\x1b\t\x12\x1>\b<±?\x117T\x2

On the server side the following arrives:

s\x1è\x1d\bÒÏ¤\x2\x10ÝËè£§\x1\x1až\x3\b2\"3\n\xf\rEÝ{Á\x15Ì\x1d“C
\x1dæx•Á\x12\xf\r²\b\r¾\x15w/õ=\x1d†³{¿\x1a\xf\rw+ŠB\x15Ò0¡A\x1dB-
\x6B*\xf\rôX\x1a?\x15è\x5G¿\x1d|k7¾2!\n\xf\rœ„ÚÂ\x15¯£ÍC\x1d6´GÂ
\x15\x1fÁ\x18C\x18ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ\x1:\x1b\tzù\x1c”hª\x1eÀ\x11jÆaê‘HIÀ
\x19\t‡

So unsurprisingly only the chars until the first \0 arrive at the server.
Does anybody know a workaround to send a byte array with \0's in it or another way to solve this problem?
The solution should be as fast as possible since the leap sensor creates about 100 frames or more (up to 200) per second and I need to get as many of them as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if `frame_string.size()` is correct, then you could use it for a `memcpy`, and drop `strlen` and `strncpy` functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with memcpy but this does not solve the problem. In my last test frame_string.size() was for example 3568 chars long but at position 64 there was a \0 and so the message_t contained only the first 63 chars.  
I edited my post

Comment: I try this code : http://cpp.sh/3mlhl . `frame_string.size()` can't return the right size

Comment: Well that's strange because for example for frame string `s\x1‚\x3\b¦¬\\\x10ƒŽœº58¶bj\xf\r\x1aÔ\x2@\x15¦0A?\x1dR˜ôC¢\x1\x1b\t\0\0\0\0.....` it returns a size of 386 although the first `\0` appears at position 39... (There was no hand detected in this frame therefore it is so small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing the message you send with the size. Currently your memcpy'ing into msg.data() but it's not been allocated.

```
    zmq::message_t message( frame_string.size() );
    memcpy(message.data(), frame_string.c_str(), frame_string.size());
    client.send(message);
```

Also, when receiving a message you don't need to have initialized it with a size, the recv call will resize it for you.

```
    zmq::message_t message;
    server.recv(&message);
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer. I start thinking that the way I access the received data may be the problem. With your solution the size of it matches perfectly the size of the sent data. I try to access it like in [one of the examples of zmq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:taskwork) via `std::string frame_string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size());`. This creates a string with the right size but totally different content...

Comment: Ahh, your using the address of the frame_string object, not the internal char array, you need to use frame_string.c_str(). Sorry, didn't spot that when originally copying your snippets. I've now edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ahh what a stupid fault. Thank you very much. It works now